# Load external text into empty div

Tags: jquery, load

I'm trying to Load external text into empty div using jquery. So, when different links are clicked, different text should appear below. This should act like an anchor link that goes to a different page, but instead fills in the empty div (on the same page). I have a demo page, but when a link is clicked, it loads all of the external text instead of the "ID" text selected. I've searched quite a bit and can't find a similar example and my javascript knowledge is obviously not good enough to solve this, so I'd appreciate any help that you can offer. Thanks!

Here is my demo page:
https://www.movingpixelsdesign.com/test/Load-start-4.html

This is my script:

```
    $('.link-clk').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var contentLink = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#show-text').load( contentLink, function(){          
        });
    });
```

Comment: This has been resolved. Turns out, it wasn’t the script…in the "href", I needed a space between the URL and the ID:
(href="text.html #food-safe")

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. Turns out, it wasn’t the script…in the "href", there needs to be a space between the URL and the ID: (href="text.html #food-safe").